# Fastest way to remove a key from array and make it last

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have to remove the 'Other' Category from the array, which is originally sorted alphabetically, and just make it the last index. I created this little helper but believe there could be a faster way of accomplishing this.

The array is something like this `[#<Category id: 17, title: "Books">, #<Category id: 18, title: "Children's Clothing">,`

Here is what I've done. It works. Although, I was wonder if theres a more efficient way.

```
<%
@options = []
@other_option = []

@free_item_options.each do |category|
    if category.title.downcase == "other"
      @other_option << category
    else
      @options << category
    end
end

@options << @other_option[0]
%>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "make it last" ?

Comment: @lacostenycoder, remove from current array, and make that option last.

Comment: @lacostenycoder `@free_item_options` has 'other' in the middle of the array. I need to be the last index of the array, thats why I separated it into two arrays, and then combined

Comment: "but believe there could be a faster way" - is it slow? How would you know if another way is faster?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I mean by better code optimization

Comment: @Victor: yes, that's what I mean too. Given two snippets of code, how can you tell which one is more optimized?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm new to Ruby so this is my solution. Maybe there would be a one liner, or cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

In cases like this, I usually reach for multi-parameter sorting.

```
@free_item_options.sort_by do |option|
  [
    option.title.casecmp?('other') ? 1 : 0,
    option.title,
  ]
end
```

"Other" category will have 1 and will sort last. Everything else will have 0 and will sort between themselves by ascending title.

Comment: `option.title.casecmp('other') == 0` could be `option.title.casecmp?('other')`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to just use SQL.

```
@free_item_options = Category.select("categories.*, (LOWER(title) = 'other') as is_other").order('is_other', :title).to_a
```

Comment: "which is originally sorted alphabetically"

Comment: @max yeah I understand. Just added another approach (since many ruby answers were provided, before they got deleted :)) in case it is a simple controller/view and `@free_item_options` is just used for this one purpose and can be modified without any other breaking changes

Answer (score 1):

There is [`Enumerable#partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) which is designed to split a collection up in two partitions.

```
@other_option, @options = @free_item_options.partition { |category| category.title.casecmp?('other') }
@options.concat(@other_options)
```

---

If you are certain there is a maximum of one "other" category (which seems to be the case based upon `@options << @other_option[0]`). You could also use [`find_index`](http://'https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) in combination with [`delete_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) and [`<<`](http://'https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-delete_at). `find_index` stops iterating upon the first match.

```
index = @free_item_options.find_index { |category| category.title.casecmp?('other') }
@free_item_options << @free_item_options.delete_at(index) if index
```

Keep in mind the above does mutate `@free_item_options`.